# How do I resize a image thumbnails in a bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, ejs

I have a website where I am displaying campsites. However, I want to resize my thumbnails on the homepage so they are all the same size in a way that the images takes up the exact same dimensions.

[Hoempage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EEiR.jpg)

The code for my page is :

```
<div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <% campsites.forEach(function(campsite){ %>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img id="homegrid" src ="<%= campsite.image %>">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4> <%= campsite.name%> </h4>
                    <h5><em><%= campsite.location %></em></h5>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <a href="/campsites/<%= campsite._id %>" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work :

```
.thumbnail #homegrid
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this most uniformly, I typically use css's background image properties. Instead of a `<img>`, you use a `<div>` with the style `background-image` set like:

```
background-image: url("/assets/s_thumb.png"); // can be set inline
```

My css for that div is normally:

```
width: 100%;
height: 165px;
background-size: 145% 145%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

Which is making the div conform to the width of the card, setting the height of the image, zooming it slightly (to account for different aspect ratios), and centering it.

Comment: div class="gridhome" background-image=url("<%= campsite.image %>");></div>

Comment: I don't think I can use an ejs element like that with background-image